Dataset with binary response collected under different environments
I'm a statistician looking for an interesting dataset with a binary response variable which was collected from different "environments" (e.g. several measurements taken in different countries or continents, in different seasons, etc.). My goal is to test a version of the invariant causal prediction algorithm, which tries to find the immediate causal drivers of some response variable. Do you have any suggestions for interesting datasets with roughly 3 to 10 covariates (continuous or categorical) and a binary response? Any help would be much appreciated!
